# Finding occurence in .txt file using array and store the value in listbox

Tags: c#, arrays

how to use array to find frequencies of an item and storing them in listbox?
[image: listbox]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add more detail about your Listbox to us,

Comment: are u able to see the image I've attached? @AliBigdeli

Comment: no i can't, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOUY7.png @AliBigdeli

Comment: read the link please...

Comment: yeah ive read, which part sir @AliBigdeli

Comment: we don't know what is happening in your code, we need more information  about your code ( contains your problem related code) to understand what is happening and help you, first of all please search in stackoverflow question carefully and then ask your question, your question unfortunately doesn't meet minimum question requirement in stackoverflow,

Comment: is it better? @AliBigdeli

Comment: Hi Jennie, we know what you want, but we do not know what your actual problem is when trying to get it. Consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63263964/edit) and adding a [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to read the text of the file and convert it to String type. then using

```
string[] array = yourString.Split(" ");
```

split text into an array of words and

```
int count = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++){
     if (array[i] == "pattern")
         count++;
}
```

Comment: Do u know how to use array to find out the frequencies of items(words)?